# Apply lag function and .when conditions to create a new variable in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, window-functions, lag

I am trying to create a new variable, "Round", to indicate treatment round that is conditional on days missed between each treatment "Event", "Gap_Day". I am trying to use the lag() function to carry forward the previous value of "Round" if the value of "Gap_Day" is less than 10 days, otherwise it would start the next treatment round (previous treatment round + 1).

I am using the window function to partition the data by patient "ID", ordered by treatment "Event".

The creation of the new variable works correctly, but only applies itself for one row and the remaining values in the window remain null. How can I get the variable creation to apply to all rows?

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lag, lead, when, first, last
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

data = sc.parallelize([
    ('A', 1, None),
    ('A', 2, 3),
    ('A', 3, 13),
    ('A', 4, 4),
    ('B', 1, None),
    ('B', 2, 22),
    ('B', 3, 3),
    ('B', 4, 14),
    ('B', 5, 11),
    ])

df_reprex = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['ID', 'Event', 'Gap_Day'])

window_def = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("Event")

df_reprex = df_reprex.withColumn("Round", when(col("Gap_Day").isNull(), 1))
df_reprex = df_reprex.withColumn("Round", when((col("Gap_Day") < 10), 
                                                   lag("Round").over(window_def))
                                          .when((col("Gap_Day") >= 10), 
                                                   lag("Round").over(window_def) + 1)
                                          .otherwise(col("Round")))

df_reprex.show()
```

This is the output of "Round" and a column I added to show what the expected output should be.

```
+---+-----+-------+-----+--------------+
| ID|Event|Gap_Day|Round|Round_Expected|
+---+-----+-------+-----+--------------+
|  A|    1|   null|    1|             1|
|  A|    2|      3|    1|             1|
|  A|    3|     13| null|             2|
|  A|    4|      4| null|             2|
|  B|    1|   null|    1|             1|
|  B|    2|     22|    2|             2|
|  B|    3|      3| null|             2|
|  B|    4|     14| null|             3|
|  B|    5|     11| null|             4|
+---+-----+-------+-----+--------------+
```

I tried adjusting the window with:

```
window_def = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("Event").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)
```

but this gave the following error message:
`AnalysisException: Cannot specify window frame for lag function.`

Thank you in advance for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do cumsum and you don't need `lag`.

```
window_def = Window.partitionBy('ID').orderBy('Event')
df_reprex = df_reprex.withColumn('Round', 
    sum(
        when(col('Gap_Day') < 10, 0).otherwise(1)
    ).over(window_def))
```